# Python get passed arguments

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, getopt

I'm working on a project which allows the user to set a path to upload files to by adding the necessary argument but for whatever reason, the upload_destination variable is always empty!
Here's my code

```
def main():
  global listen
  global port
  global execute
  global command
  global upload_destination
  global target

  if not len(sys.argv[1:]):
     usage()
  try:
     opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hle:t:p:cu", ["help", "listen", "execute", "target", "port", "command", "upload"])
  except getopt.GetoptError as err:
     print str(err)
     usage()

  for o,a in opts:
     if o in ("-h", "--help"):
         usage()
     elif o in ("-l", "--listen"):
         listen = True
     elif o in ("-e", "--execute"):
         execute = True
     elif o in ("-c", "--commandshell"):
         command = True
     elif o in ("-u", "--upload"):
         #Here's the problem, a is empty even though I include a path
         upload_destination = a
     elif o in ("-t", "--target"):
         target = a
     elif o in ("-p", "--port"):
         port = int(a)
     else:
         assert False, "Unhandled Option"

  if not listen and len(target) and port > 0:
     buffer = sys.stdin.read()
     client_sender(buffer)

  if listen:
     server_loop()
```

I call the programm by entering

```
C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\PythonTest>python test.py -l -c -p 3500 -u C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Test
```

Comment: Why not to use `argparse` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)?

Comment: May not be related at all, but try use forward slashes instead. Like if you were to have `s = "something/new"`, it'd end up as `s = "something(newline)ew"`

Comment: @Peter I also thought of this so I tried by simply entering Test and it still was empty

Comment: Are you completely certain that the `elif` block is executing at all? If you put a `print("about to change upload destination")` on the line before `upload_destination = a`, does it get printed?

Comment: @Kevin Yes it does, I tried it multiple times

Comment: Silly question, forgive me for asking, but are you are calling `main()` from somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a simple missing colon `:`.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html

> options is the string of option letters that the script wants to recognize, with options that require an argument followed by a colon (':'; i.e., the same format that Unix getopt() uses).

Change the `"hle:t:p:cu"` to `"hle:t:p:cu:"` and it should work (at least it did work for me with Win7/Python3.5).

When you execute `print(opts, args)` with your code, you get:

```
([('-l', ''), ('-c', ''), ('-p', '3500'), ('-u', '')], ['C:UsersAsusDesktopTest'])
```

with the added colon it becomes:

```
([('-l', ''), ('-c', ''), ('-p', '3500'), ('-u', 'C:UsersAsusDesktopTest')], [])
```

Without the colon `C:\Users\...` becomes a new argument.